# c - Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast

Tags: c

```
void getFormattedTime(int inputSeconds, int* totalHours, int* totalMinutes, int* totalSeconds) {

   totalHours = (inputSeconds / 3600);
   totalMinutes = (inputSeconds - (3600 * *totalHours)) / 60;
   totalSeconds = (inputSeconds - (*totalHours * 3600) - (*totalMinutes*60));   
   printf("Formatted Total Time: %d:%d:%d", *totalHours, 
   *totalMinutes, *totalSeconds);

}
```

I keep getting a assignment makes pointer from integer without cast error and I really don't know how to fix it. Please help!

Comment: And the error does not mention the line-number?

Comment: So, you know you need the `*` in the printf, so why wouldn't you also need it to assign values to the ints that are pointed at by your variables?

Comment: If you don't understand the error message (which, I believe, very straightforward), keep minimizing your code until you find the minimal expression with error.

Comment: Thanks for the advise! Its just that I'm still not proficient enough with pointers and how they work so I couldn't understand why I was getting a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed assigining integer to pointer. Try this:

```
*totalHours = (inputSeconds / 3600);
*totalMinutes = (inputSeconds - (3600 * *totalHours)) / 60;
*totalSeconds = (inputSeconds - (*totalHours * 3600) - (*totalMinutes*60));
```

Comment: I am answering very kindly to a newbie. How could guys down vote such a nice answer :)?